# Jquery reg ex replace - nth occurence of integer within multi dimensional array

Tags: jquery, regex, multidimensional-array, replace

I'm not sure if this is possible, I have spent all afternoon struggling with it.

I have a table with rows of inputs, the inputs have the following names to define a multidimensional array.

attribute_set[1][options][**1**][attr_id]

attribute_set[1][options][**1**][attr_stock]

attribute_set[1][options][**1**][attr_price]

attribute_set[1][options][**2**][attr_id]

attribute_set[1][options][**2**][attr_stock]

attribute_set[1][options][**2**][attr_price]

Using a real world example *attribute_set* may be say 'Length' of a product, and each *options* would be lengths available (1m, 2m etc.) Each length *options* may have a unique stock level or price. so for example [options][1][attr_name], [options][1][attr_stock], [options][1][attr_price].

The user can click 'add attribute' and define a new row of attributes using Jquery. Each time this is clicked I need to be able to increment the second integer key in the string, for example:

Using the above set of attributes, the user clicks 'add attribute', I need to create an input with the name:

attribute_set[2][options][**4**][attr_name], attribute_set[2][options][**4**][attr_stock] - then 5,6,7 etc.

I have the clone functionality working, but each time a row of inputs is created I can't quite figure out how to increment the number. I have been experimenting with reg ex to extract the integer value of the attribute, and narrowed it down to:

(?:options])[(\d+)]

http://www.rubular.com/r/NpLrCerx8K

My jquery function is below:

```
    $(".add_option").on('click', function() {
        var $tableBody = $(this).prev('.attr-tbl').find("tbody"),
        $trLast = $tableBody.find("tr:last"),
        $trNew = $trLast.clone(true).insertAfter($trLast);


        $trNew.find('input:text').val('');
        $trNew.find('select').prop('selectedIndex',0);
        $trNew.find('input:text, select, input:checkbox').each(function(){
            //console.log(this.name);
            this.value = '';
            this.name.replace(/(?:options])\[(\d+)]/, function(str,p1){
                console.log(str + p1);
                return (parseInt(p1,10)+1);
            });
        })

    });
```

The above returns in the console:

str = options][1]
p1 = 1

But crucially when the next row of inputs is created the key doesn't increment. I have this working for the first integer key using the below, but I'm struggling to replicate this to change the second key only.

```
        $newSet.find('input:text, select, input:checkbox').each(function(){
                    //console.log(this.name);
                    this.value = '';
                    this.name = this.name.replace(/\[(\d+)\]/, function(str,p1){
                        console.log(str + p1);
                        return '[' + (parseInt(p1,10)+1) + ']';
                    });
        })
```

Any help would be much appreciated, many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anybody stumbles on this page, the above was over-complicating matters. I settled on this:

```
    $(".add_option").on('click', function() {
        var $tableBody = $(this).prev('.attr-tbl').find("tbody"),
        $trLast = $tableBody.find("tr:last"),
        $trNew = $trLast.clone(true).insertAfter($trLast);

        $trNew.find('input:text').val('');
        $trNew.find('select').prop('selectedIndex',0);
        $trNew.find('input:text, select, input:checkbox').each(function(){
            this.value = '';
            newNum = increment_last(this.name);
            this.name = newNum;
        })
```

});

and the function to increment the second number is:

```
function increment_last(v) {
    return v.replace(/[0-9]+(?!.*[0-9])/, function(match) {
        return parseInt(match, 10)+1;
    });
}
```